# Error con el grindview aparece en una columna sy deberia de aparecer en diferentes filas

Tags: android-studio

La idea es qeu con un grindview meta las letas del abecedarios deneria quedar

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

Pero me lo mete todo en una sola columna.
Os dejo el codigo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private TextView tv1;
    static final String[] letras = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
            "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "Ñ", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S","T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gw1);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, letras);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String resultado = (String) ((TextView) v).getText();
                tv1.setText(resultado);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

En la parte grafica solo esta el gridview y un textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no es un error, define en tu [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView) el numero de columnas mediante la propiedad `android:numColumns`:

puedes realizarlo directamente en el layout:

```
<GridView
...
...
android:numColumns="3"/>
```

o programaticamente mediante el método

[setNumColumns(int numColumns)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns(int))

de esta forma:

```
gridView.setNumColumns(3);
```

Comment: gracias ya funciona perfecto :P error de novato

Comment: Excelente, saludos.